# Type error when trying to push in a model's array Prisma, TypeScript, MongoDB

Tags: typescript, mongodb, prisma

I don't know what type I should use in the following case:

Here is a part of my schema.prisma file:

```
model Device {
  id            String         @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  modules       Module[]
  sensorRecords SensorRecord[]
  plant         Plant?         @relation(fields: [plantId], references: [id])
  plantId       String?        @db.ObjectId
  User          User?          @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId        String?        @db.ObjectId
}

type SensorRecord {
  sensorRecords IndividualSensorRecord
}

type IndividualSensorRecord {
  sensorUnit  String
  sensorData  Float?
  sensorState Boolean
  recordDate  DateTime @default(now())
}
```

And here is the file where I encounter my problem:

```
import SensorDataRecord from '../interfaces/SensorDataRecord'
import prisma from '../utils/PrismaClient'

export default async function createSensorDataRecord (deviceId: string, data: SensorDataRecord): Promise<void> {
  const records: any = [ // fix this
    {
      sensorUnit: 'lm',
      sensorData: data.luminosity !== undefined ? data.luminosity : null,
      sensorState: data.luminosity !== undefined
    },
    {
      sensorUnit: 'S/m',
      sensorData: data.electro_conductivity !== undefined ? data.electro_conductivity : null,
      sensorState: data.electro_conductivity !== undefined
    },
    {
      sensorUnit: 'liters',
      sensorData: data.water_level !== undefined ? data.water_level : null,
      sensorState: data.water_level !== undefined
    },
    {
      sensorUnit: 'pH',
      sensorData: data.ph !== undefined ? data.ph : null,
      sensorState: data.ph !== undefined
    }
  ]

  await prisma.device.update({
    where: {
      id: deviceId
    },
    data: {
      sensorRecords: {
        push: records
      }
    }
  })
}
```

I need help at the line 5 (// fix this comment). I don't know what the correct type should be. For now, only setting the variable as `any` type have worked.

I already tried IndividualSensorRecord[] but when I do so, I get the following error line 34 (in the update statement):

```
Type '{ push: IndividualSensorRecord[]; }' is not assignable to type '(Without<SensorRecordListUpdateEnvelopeInput, SensorRecordCreateInput> & SensorRecordCreateInput) | (Without<...> & SensorRecordListUpdateEnvelopeInput) | (Without<...> & SensorRecordCreateInput[])'.
  Types of property 'push' are incompatible.
    Type 'IndividualSensorRecord[]' is not assignable to type 'Enumerable<SensorRecordCreateInput> | ((...items: SensorRecordCreateInput[]) => number) | undefined'.
      Type 'IndividualSensorRecord[]' is not assignable to type 'SensorRecordCreateInput[]'.
        Type 'IndividualSensorRecord' has no properties in common with type 'SensorRecordCreateInput'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(4771, 5): The expected type comes from property 'sensorRecords' which is declared here on type '(Without<DeviceUpdateInput, DeviceUncheckedUpdateInput> & DeviceUncheckedUpdateInput) | (Without<...> & DeviceUpdateInput)'
```

I also tried without typing the variable or not pushing an array but a single value, but I've got the same error.